# Error #NAME? after putting formula from Visual FoxPro into the Excel cell

Tags: excel, automation, visual-foxpro

I populate an existing Excel spreadsheet using Visual FoxPro automation. If I put the valid Excel formula `=SUM(D2:D4)` I get **#NAME?** error. When I confirm (that is, I click on cell and press enter) that cell (with no changes), this error disappears. I use Excel 2007 Polish version, so proper formula is `=SUMA(D2:D4)`.

Here is the part of code:

```
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.visible = .T.
oExcel.Application.UserControl=.T.
oExcel.Application.Interactive=.T.
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = .F.

oWorkbook = oExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open("&xfile")
oExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Autofit
tFormula = "=SUMA(D2:D4)"
tCell = "D5"

oExcel.Range("&tCell").Value = [&tFormula]
```

As You see, I turned off `DisplayAlerts`. Even if I manually turn off formulas checking by Option-Formulas in Excel it doesn't help.

Comment: You are putting the formula in as the cell's value. Trying modifying the assignment with `oExcel.Range("&tCell").Formula = [&tFormula]`.

Comment: I've just tested this solution - doesn't work.

Comment: I'd get rid of the macros. I imagine they're messing things up. Try oExcel.Range(m.tCell).Formula = m.tFormula

Comment: I've tried with no success. I think that there is a bug in the polish version of Excel. Thanks.